# How to retrieve Profile data using OpenID authentication? ( Zend Framework )

Tags: zend-framework, authentication, openid

I read some tutorials and came up with the following script to authenticate with OpenID. But I don't know how to retrieve profile data of the user logged in, like fullname, or email. can anyone help me with that?

```
$status='';
$auth=Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$post=array();
$get=$this->getRequest()->getParams();
if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
    $post=$this->getRequest()->getPost();
}
$profile=new Zend_OpenId_Extension_Sreg(array(
    'nickname' => true,
    'email'    => true,
    'fullname' => true),null,1.1
);

if($auth->hasIdentity()){
    if(isset($get['openid_action']) && $get['openid_action']=='logout'){
        $auth->clearIdentity();
        $status="logged Out";
    }else{
        $status="logged in as ".$auth->getIdentity();   
    }
}else if(isset($post['openid_action']) && $post['openid_action']=='login' && $post['openid_identifier']){
    $result=$auth->authenticate(new Zend_Auth_Adapter_OpenId($post['openid_identifier']));
    $status='something went wrong';
}else if(isset($get['openid_mode'])){
    $result=$auth->authenticate(new Zend_Auth_Adapter_OpenId());
    if(!$result->isValid()){
        $auth->clearIdentity();
    }
    $status.= implode('
',$result->getMessages());

}else{
    $status='You are not logged in';
}
$this->view->status=$status;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out how to do that:

```
$status='';
$auth=Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$post=array();
$get=$this->getRequest()->getParams();
if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
    $post=$this->getRequest()->getPost();
}

//changed nickname and fullname to false, so if provider didn't provide these, authentication won't fail.
$profile=new Zend_OpenId_Extension_Sreg(array(
    'nickname' => false,
    'email'    => true,
    'fullname' => false),null,1.1
);

if($auth->hasIdentity()){
    if(isset($get['openid_action']) && $get['openid_action']=='logout'){
        $auth->clearIdentity();
        $status="logged Out";
    }else{
        $status="logged in as ".$auth->getIdentity();   
    }
}else if(isset($post['openid_action']) && $post['openid_action']=='login' && $post['openid_identifier']){
    $result=$auth->authenticate(new Zend_Auth_Adapter_OpenId($post['openid_identifier'],null,null,null,$profile));
    $status='something went wrong';
}else if(isset($get['openid_mode'])){
    $result=$auth->authenticate(new Zend_Auth_Adapter_OpenId(null,null,null,null,$profile));
    if(!$result->isValid()){
        $auth->clearIdentity();
    }else{
        //here you have the information you need.
        $info=$profile->getProperties();
    }
    $status.= implode('
',$result->getMessages());

}else{
    $status='You are not logged in';
}
$this->view->status=$status;
```

But if you want to use google or yahoo, or any OpenId 2.0 provider, you should [use patches](http://ak33m.com/?p=71).